# Other way to save params using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I created a form to save information everything is working fine, but my question is if exists other way to save params?

Here is the view:

```
<% form_for @job, :url => {:controller=>"subject",:action=>'create'} do |f|%>
  <%= f.text_field :subject  %> 

  <%= text_field_tag "new_subject",:new_subject  %> 
<% end %>
```

Is there any other way to save Without f.text_field :new_subject ?

Here is the log

```
Processing SubjectController#create (for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-16 11:22:00) [POST]
Parameters: {"subject"=>{"subject"=>"This is a test"}, "new_subject"=>"This is other text", "commit"=>"Crea Factura", "authenticity_token"=>"LOL"}
Subject Columns (0.5ms)   SHOW FIELDS FROM `subjects`
SQL (0.1ms)   BEGIN
Test Create (0.2ms)   INSERT INTO `subjects` (`subject`, ` new_subject`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES('This is a test', NULL,'2014-06-16', '2014-06-16 16:22:00')
SQL (26.1ms)   COMMIT
```

Like the log says:

```
Is saving NULL because is not inside the first bracket
```

Also I tried:

```
<input id="new_subject" name="new_subject" type="text" />
```

Please somebody can help me?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do? If you want to copy a parameter from the `params` hash into your model there's nothing stopping you from doing that. Or you could use an `attr_accessor`, e.g., a non-persisted field, to capture the data in the model itself, and copy it somewhere else in the process.

Comment: I suppose this line `<%= text_field_tag "new_subject",:new_subject  %>`  should be just like `<%= f.text_field :new_subject  %>`

Comment: @Pavan I know that , just want other way or is the only way that exists?

Comment: I guess it the only way.Can you post your `create action` and related `strong parameters method` of your `SubjectController`?

Comment: Thanks Pavan but someone gave me the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input id="new_subject" name="subject[new_subject]" type="text" />
```